# Остановить timertask при boolean == TRUE

Tags: java, java-timertask

Необходимо каждую минуту проверять значение "some" на true/false и при some== true останавливать таймер. Как его остановить в этом коде я понять не могу.

```java
class SayHello extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        try {
            parser();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void parser() throws IOException, JSONException {
        String a = "ссылка";
        String url = "тоже ссылка" + a;
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        JSONObject json = Request.readJsonFromUrl(url);
        System.out.println(json.toString());
        System.out.println(json.get("some"));


        boolean some;
        if ((0 == json.getInt("some"))) some = false;
        else if ((1 == json.getInt("some"))) some = false;
        else some = true;
    }
}
```

а также:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, 60000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `timer.stop()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean some;
    if ((0 == json.getInt("some"))||(1 == json.getInt("some")) ){ 
         some = false;
    }
    else {
         some = true;
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

А в  `public void run() {}` добавьте обработку interrupt исключения

Answer (score 0):

Можно возможно так.

```java
public class Main {
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    class SayHello extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String a = "ссылка";
                String url = "тоже ссылка" + a;
                URL obj = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                JSONObject json = Request.readJsonFromUrl(url);
                System.out.println(json.toString());
                System.out.println(json.get("some"));

                if ((0 == json.getInt("some")) || 1 == json.getInt("some")) {
                    timer.cancel(); // Для отключение только текущей задачи
                    timer.purge(); // Для удаление всех задач
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.timer.schedule(main.new SayHello(), 0, 60000);
    }
}
```